# Why retrieved value from database is not shown in text box?

Tags: c#, .net

Why the values I have retrieved from database are not shown in textbox? I have written the following code but it does not work. I have kept in mind that this code is written on form load event. Please do tell me the mistake I have done?

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(Common.GetDBConnectionString()))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("P.ID from dbo.Tb_Patient", myConnection))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myConnection.Open();

        //SqlParameter custId = (cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbo.Tb_Patient", 10));

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                string nameValue = reader["P.ID"].ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("value is:",nameValue);

                txtid.Text = nameValue;


            }
            else {

                MessageBox.Show("Data is not retrived");
            }
      }
  }
}
```

Update from comment:

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Patient]( [P.Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [P.Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL, [P.Age] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL, [P.Contact] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL, [P.Date] [datetime] NULL, [P.Occupation] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL, [P.Gender] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_Tb_Patient] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [P.Id] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]`

Comment: `new SqlCommand("P.ID from dbo.Tb_Patient", myConnection)` isn't it should be `new SqlCommand("select P.ID from dbo.Tb_Patient P", myConnection)`

Answer (score 3):

This line doesn't seems to be a valid SQL query, nor the name of a stored procedure:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("P.ID from dbo.Tb_Patient", myConnection))
```

Probably the correct text is:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [P.ID] from dbo.Tb_Patient", myConnection))
```

And of course that it's not a stored procedure but a normal command text:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

**EDIT:** After seeing the schema of your table I have corrected the answer. The only error is in the command text passed to the database engine lacking of the SELECT clause at the beginning. However you need to enclose in square brackets the field name `P.ID`.

I suggest to change the field names. This naming schema is really confusing because it is used when you need to prefix a name present in more than one table joined together.

[See:  ALIAS of a name](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: thanx to all but Error 1 Syntax error, ',' expected is occured now if i add this CommandType statement?

Comment: I can't see the schema of your table, but I will try to remove the table alias because in this case is not needed: `select ID from Tb_Patient`

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Patient](
 [P.Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [P.Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [P.Age] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [P.Contact] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [P.Date] [datetime] NULL,
 [P.Occupation] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [P.Gender] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Tb_Patient] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [P.Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: Well. that's really weird. You have a table where the name of every field is prefixed with `P.`. Why? this is really confusing and it doesn't add anything to the meaning of these fields. I suppose now that you need to use that P. before the names. But I strongly suggest to remove it from the field names.

Comment: Updated the answer, now I have removed the alias behind the table name (tb_patient P) and the reader should use P.ID as before. But again, do not use this strange and confusing naming schema

Comment: If you have removed the P in front of the field names on the table I need to return to the previous version of my answer, if you still have the P in front then this answer works for me. What error message do you get?

Comment: cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;  in this statement Syntax error ',' expected

Comment: Well, CommandType.Text is the default so I think you could remove all the line, however that statement should not give any kind of error.

Comment: Could you post the connection string? I have a suspect, but I need to see your  connection string returned by `Common.GetDBConnectionString()`

Comment: "Data Source=ABBASI-PC; Initial Catalog=ESDFDB; Integrated Security=True;"

Comment: Nope, I give up, I hope that it works without the CommandType line.

Comment: thanks Steve but its z not working. please see my code from some other plate form....like team viewer etc

Comment: I will like to see your Whole project. You could post a zip on some sharing site like SkyDrive, GDrive, DropBox, MediaFire and post here the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use either a stored procedure or a valid SQL statement

```
select P.ID from dbo.Tb_Patient as P
```

Comment: thanx to all but Error 1 Syntax error, ',' expected is occured now if i add this CommandType statement?

Answer (score 0):

- If you're not sure whether the database is case insensitive, then always use the same name as in the creation. `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Patient]( [P.Id] [int] ...`
- Terminate the command string with  `;`.

try it with

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [P.Id] from dbo.Tb_Patient;";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection  = myConnection;
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read())
        {
            string nameValue = reader["P.Id"].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("value is:",nameValue);
            txtid.Text = nameValue;
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Data is not retrieved");
        }

    reader.Close();
}
```